# Clearing setInterval() Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `setInterval` on a function X that runs every 500ms. In this function X, I call another function Y that essentially binds an event on some `div`s. However, I would like to unbind these events the next time the function X is called (to start "fresh"). My code doesn't seem to work:

```
setInterval(this.board.updateBoard, 500); //called from another constructor
```

This then initiates the functions below:

```
Board.prototype.updateBoard = function() {
    //I attempt to unbind ALL my divs
    var divs = this.$el.find("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        $(divs[i]).unbind(); //Apparently this doesn't work?
    }

    //...some code here...
    //find appropriate $div's (multiple of them), and then calls this.beginWalking() below on each of those 
    //loop here
    this.beginWalking($div, direction + "0", direction + "1");
    //end of loop
}

//alternate between classes to give appearance of walking
Board.prototype.beginWalking = function ($div, dir0, dir1) { 
    return setInterval(function () {
        if ($div.hasClass(dir0)) {
            $div.removeClass(dir0);
            $div.addClass(dir1);
        } else {
            $div.removeClass(dir1);
            $div.addClass(dir0);            
        }
    }.bind(this), 80);
};
```

Basically, `updateBoard` is called every 500ms. Each time it's called, `beginWalking` is called to set another interval on a `div`. The purpose of this other interval, which functions correctly, is to add and remove a class every 80ms. I just can't seem to unbind everything before the next `updateBoard` is called.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: It seems you're binding events to the board class itself, not divs.

Comment: Where is your code for binding the events?  `function() { }.bind(this)` is not the same bind as `$("selector").bind()`.  Are you wanting to clearInterval (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I made a big mistake in making a distinction between the two. Sorry about that!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`clearInterval()`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html)
edit: `$(selector).toggleClass(dir0)` might also be helpful

```
// In other file, use a global (no var) if you need to read it from another file:
updaterGlobal = setInterval(this.board.updateBoard, 500);

// store interval references for clearing:
var updaterLocals = [];
Board.prototype.updateBoard = function() {
    //I attempt to unbind ALL my divs
    var divs = this.$el.find("div");
    // Stop existing div timers:
    while(updaterLocals.length > 0){
      clearInterval(updaterLocals[0]);
      updaterLocals.shift(); // remove the first timer
    }

    //...some code here...
    //loop here to call the below on several $div's
    this.beginWalking($div, direction + "0", direction + "1");
    //end of loop
}

//alternate between classes to give appearance of walking
Board.prototype.beginWalking = function ($div, dir0, dir1) { 
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if ($div.hasClass(dir0)) {
            $div.removeClass(dir0);
            $div.addClass(dir1);
        } else {
            $div.removeClass(dir1);
            $div.addClass(dir0);            
        }
    }.bind(this), 80);
    // Save the timer:
    updaterLocals.push(interval);
    return;
};
```